# Linker Error prevents me from initializing TA-LIB in C++

Tags: c++, ta-lib

I'm having a problem with TA-LIB in my C++ project.

I just downloaded TA-lib (ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip) and copy-and-pasted c folder to my project folder.

Because of a linker error, I can't go any further.

What I did:

1. I just downloaded TA-lib (ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip) and copy-and-pasted c folder to my project folder.
2. include "c\include\ta_libc.h"

Is there anything wrong with my steps? Or any steps I missed?

[image: Screenshot]

@AlenL
Thank you for your help.

[image]

I included every proj files in IDE.

But the result is the same.

+) Error List

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _TA_Shutdown referenced in function _main

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _TA_Initialize referenced in function _main

LNK1120 2 unresolved externals

Comment: Did you check this?: [SO: What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/7478597)

Comment: Please copy the error and paste the text in your post, so that users can easily see what issues you're encountering. This will make it much easier to help fix the problem.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Posted, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the ta-lib\c\ide\vs2005\lib_proj folder and it's subfolders. You need to include the .vcproj files from the subfolders into your solution.

Comment: Would you check my post again?

Comment: Ok, they are there, and I suppose they can be built. Now you should also add a proper library (or libraries) as dependencies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2017), so they are built before your project.
Additionally, you will have to make sure they are also linked with your project. Depending on version of VS and project/solution settings, that might or might not happen automatically as soon as you add them as dependencies.